# The product of two Trigonometrical functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question:
Express the following as the product of two trigonometrical functions:

$$\sin(4 \theta) - 6 \sin(6 \theta)$$

Here is my attempt, is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: No it is not correct . $\sin (4a)\neq 4\sin cos..

Comment: That is not a product. So it is wrong. And $sin4\theta$ is not equal to $4sin\theta cos\theta$. Same for $sin6\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that

$$\sin (2a)=2\sin (a)\cos (a) $$
and
$$\sin (3b)=3\sin(b)-4\sin^3 (b) $$

we find
$$\sin (4t)=2\sin (2t)\cos (2t) $$
and
$$\sin (6t)=3\sin(2t)-4\sin^3(2t) $$
the difference gives

$$\sin (2t)(2\cos (2t)-3+4(1-\cos^2 (2t)) $$
$$=\sin (2t)\left(4\cos^2 (2t)+2\cos (2t)+1\right) $$

Answer (score 3):

Use the trigonometric identity
$$\sin A - \sin B = 2 \cos \frac{A+B}{2} \sin \frac{A-B}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $$\sin { \alpha -\sin { \beta  } =2\sin { \frac { \alpha -\beta  }{ 2 } \cos { \frac { \alpha +\beta  }{ 2 }  }  }  } $$